# Flutter Error waiting for a debug connection: Bad state: No element

Tags: flutter

I try to run flutter with `CTRL+F5` in real-device but keep getting the error and blackscreen even with the simple HelloWorld App. However with the command `flutter run` in the terminal in VSCode, it displayed the view in device but terminal showed error as well.

`Error waiting for a debug connection: Bad state: No element`

[image]

Any idea how to solve the error?

Comment: Can flutter see the device as an available device?

Comment: yeah.... it can ...